# How do I prevent Fiddler from blocking random websites?

Tags: fiddler

I am using Fiddler2 by Telerik and running into a weird issue where the program is blocking some websites. Here's an example of it randomly blocking www.slacker.com.

[image]

Now usually when this comes up I can close Fiddler and refresh the page and it would come up without a problem. However, since I updated Fiddler to the latest version it's started doing this:

[image]

Why in the world does Fiddler do this and how do I stop it from breaking random websites?

I found another post on stackoverflow where someone suggested using a custom OnBeforeRequest rule like this:

```
if (oSession.fullUrl == "http://slacker.com"){
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "do not want to see";
}
```

I've tried adding this into the custom rules but it did not seem to fix anything. I have also tried setting Fiddler to only listen to traffic from IE since IE is mostly what I want to see traffic from.

Is there a setting somewhere within Fiddler that will fix this or do I just need to find a different program?

**Edit:**
Additional information: I'm running version v4.4.8.4 of Fiddler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with Fiddler.

The problem is with the TCP/IP stack on your computer, which is why Chrome cannot connect to the site either.

Are you running any firewall software? Are you on a managed corporate network, or a home ISP?

If you type `prefs show fiddler.network.egress.IP` and hit Enter inside the black QuickExec box below the Web Sessions list, what do you see?

Answer (score 1):

- Whenever you open fiddler 1 root certificate installed on your machine and also Proxy setting will be saved under Internet browser > LAN Setting > Uncheck that and it  will work.